# i found that error in my code /mnt/sdcard/recycle: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android, io

```
String inputPath= mFilePathTextView.getText().toString();
System.out.println("paa"+inputPath);

File outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/recycle/");
System.out.println("paaa"+outputPath);
// File (or directory) to be moved
//String outputPath="/mnt/sdcard/";
//File dir = new File(outputPath);

if (!outputPath.exists()) {
    outputPath.mkdir();
}

in = new FileInputStream(inputPath);        
out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

in.close();
out.close();
// delete the original file
//new File(inputPath).delete();
```

I am successfully creating a folder but file is not copying on this folder. I want to move any type file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps you

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
  File  fDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"recycle");
```

Now check File is exist ot not, also make sure you added required permision in `AndroidManifest.xml` File

Comment: ok but i want after moved its again restore on previous location.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042855/i-would-like-to-setlastmodification-time-and-date-in-below-this-code